# Openstack Glance image create "The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)"

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, openstack-glance

When I try to create an image, I encounter a problem - The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)

I do the following steps
edit the /etc/glance/glance-api.conf

```
[database] 
connection = mysql+pymysql://glance:glance@localhost/glance
[DEFAULT]
rabbit_password = openstack
rabbit_userid = openstack
rabbit_host = localhost
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = glance
password = openstack
memcached_servers = controller:11211
[paste_deploy]
flavor = keystone
[glance_store]
stores = file,http
default_store = file
filesystem_store_datadir = /var/lib/glance/images/
```

Edit the /etc/glance/glance-registry.conf

```
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://glance:glance@localhost/glance
[keystone_authtoken]
auth_uri = http://controller:5000
auth_url = http://controller:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = glance
password = openstack
memcached_servers = controller:11211
[paste_deploy]
flavor = keystone
```

sync DB
root@controller:~# su -s /bin/sh -c "glance-manage db_sync" glance

And while create image get eror

```
root@controller:~# openstack image create "cirros-0.4.0-x86_64" --file /tmp/cirros-0.4.0-x86_64-disk.img --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --public
(http://controller:35357/v2/schemas/image): The resource could not be found. (HTTP 404)
root@controller:~#

openstack --version
openstack 3.12.2

glance-api --version
15.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im edit my .rc and it works

```
root@controller:~# env | grep ^OS
OS_REGION_NAME=RegionOne
OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME=default
OS_IMAGE_API_VERSION=2
OS_PROJECT_NAME=service
OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
OS_PASSWORD=openstack
OS_DOMAIN_NAME=default
OS_AUTH_TYPE=password
OS_AUTH_URL=http://controller:35357/v3
OS_USERNAME=glance
OS_URL=http://controller:35357/v3
OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_NAME=default
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you use the wrong port. `35357` is the port of keystone, but `openstack image create` should trigger the port of glance, which is by default `9292`. I think you have not configured the correct ports for the openstack endpoints. These should have been created by the `openstack endpoint create` command.

Comment: `| internal  |  http://controller:9292 |`
`| public    |  http://controller:9292 |`
`| |admin   |  http://controller:9292 |`

I configure edpoints with default ports